# Python - Pandas - Convert date column in format 2018-01-01 to string version of timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date column in format 2018-01-01

Need to convert it a timestamp value.

But then the timestamp value needs to be converted to its string equivalent.

contrived example:

```
print(myDf["myDateColumn"])
0   2018-03-01
1   NaT
```

--some solution--

```
print(myDf["myConvertedDateValueAsTextVersionOf10DigitTimestamp"])
0     1322697600.0
1
```

Have done quite a bit of searching/trying. Can't get the date into a timestamp and  can't get the timestamp into a string.

Comment: note the two dates above don't match up; but the intent should be otherwise clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `int` and mask `NaT`s, like this.

```
df["UnixTimestamp"] = s.astype(int).floordiv(1e9).mask(s.isna(), '').astype(str)
```

```
print(df["UnixTimestamp"])

0    1519862400
1              
Name: UnixTimestamp, dtype: object
```

Note that the column is of type `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert String to Datetime Object then get the timestamp.

```
import datetime    
datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-03-01','%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
```

Result

```
1519842600.0
```

Now this can be implemented for the dataframe like this. New  *TimeStamp* column can be created in this way.

```
df = df.assign(TimeStamp = [datetime.datetime.strptime(val,'%Y-%m-%d').timestamp() for val in df.date.values])
```